# MS access password protect for other users

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2010

1.I have created a MS access db, where list of values are present in single excel column.
Then i have created a 2 form first is background and 2nd is sku search.As in the screenshot.
The use of the serach text is to searcha data from the list and gives result if present.
I want to share it to different user.But i dont want them to edit it.
Now if i select "Alt+f11", then Design mode and it allows to edit.
I want the different user should not see the excel data.

2. In future i might edit the access to insert new data.So it should have the option to insert/edit the value only to me.
   Ideally user will place the MS access it in their local drive and use it.
   **I am using MS 2010.** please help. or if i set any password protected then it will be vey good so different user can not enable the content. is it possible?

[image]

Comment: 1) Split the database into a Front-End and Back-End, with the Back-End stored on a network path that everyone can access. 2) Make the SKU look-up data into a form that and set the form properties to disallow editing / additions / deletions. You can always edit the table directly when you need to. You can also hide the Navigation Pane. Most users won't know how to find the table without the Navigation Pane.

Comment: how to split it, do i need to create two different access sheet? and is it not possible to set any password or so?
in a single access is it not possible?

Comment: read up on splitting database. it's very easy. but I think all you need to do is make the 2nd form "read-only" by turning off edit / add / deletion in the form properties.

Comment: if i will make the 2nd as "read only" will i be able to edit the data my self in future?

Comment: I don't know your exact design, but you can edit the table directly that form is based on.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want them to edit the data, then make textbox.enabled = False (this is on the Data tab of the Property sheet).

If you want to make it so the user can't edit the form, you can trap for f11 in the On Key Down event of the form itself.  It's been a while since I've done that, but I believe this will work:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

    Select Case KeyCode
        Case vbKeyF11
            KeyCode = 0
            MsgBox "Access not allowed"
        Case Else
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: my intent is to prevent the data from editing from the user end.not from my end.I might add more value in the access in future.So is there any protected function in access so the user who take a copy can not access the data .

Comment: Well, you can put a button on the form that pops up a modal form and asks for a password.  If the password is correct, you can turn the textbox.enabled to True and be allowed to edit the data.  However, disabling the F11 key should prevent anyone from getting into the table.  You'll also have to disable the Shift/Enter combination (that's a whole other issue), but that should pretty much lock the database down from anyone messing with the data.